# MVC Area with same namespace as referenced project

Tags: model-view-controller, namespaces, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm having a problem accessing a referenced project. I'm using areas and one of my areas has a simular namespace as a project I've referenced. So the namespace of my area is...

AdminSite.Areas.MyProject

...and the namespace of the referenced project is...

MyProject

So when I try to access classes in the referenced project 'MyProject', it only looks in the AdminSite.Areas.MyProject namespace. So how do I access classes in the 'MyProject' namespace instead of the 'AdminSite.Areas.MyProject' namespace?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know you said it's referenced, but double-check to ensure that you didn't just add it to the solution.  It needs to be added as a reference in the MVC project.

Comment: Yes it's definitely referenced. I'm able to reference it in class files using the 'using' keyword, so I know it's referenced.

Comment: Another stupid question; have you tried MyProject.MyClass1, etc...?

Comment: Yes tried that. I found the answer anyway....I needed to prefix MyProject with global:: to pick up the correct namespace with intellisense.